General argument strategy for counting functions in AP's
For concreteness I'll refer to the divisor function but just pick your favourite multiplicative $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb C$.
If I want to estimate $$\sum _{n\leq x}d(n)$$ then I can write it as $$\int _{(2)}\frac {\zeta (s)^2x^sds}{s}$$ and move the contour to the left. Moving it to $\sigma =1/2$ already gives a result but better is to move it past the critical strip and use the functional equation for $\zeta (s)$ to write $\zeta (s)$ as a Dirichlet series at $1-s$. Then a better bound is possible. (In fact a bound $\mathcal O(x^{1/3})$ after using some estimates on exponential integrals - this is of course all standard, and can be found e.g. in Titchmarsh. (And what's really going on is it's the first part of proving Voronoi's formula.))
If I want to estimate $$\sum _{n\leq x\atop {n\equiv a(q)}}d(n)$$ then I can write it as (assume $(a,q)=1$) $$\frac {1}{\phi (q)}\sum _{\chi (q)}\overline {\chi }(a)\int _{(2)}\frac {L_\chi(s)^2x^sds}{s}$$ and again I can move the integral to the left and bound the $L_\chi (s)$ in the critical strip. But I could also as above move the integral past the strip and use the functional equation to write $L_\chi (s)$ as a Dirichlet series. This time it's a bit more involved than above because I have the $\Sigma _\chi $ too, which I'll need to then sum over an expression involving $L_\chi (1-s)^2$.
My question: I would like to see an example of this argument somewhere - can anyone provide a reference? So precisely what I'm asking is I'd like to see the count of any function in AP's being evaluated using Perron's formula for an individual character, the integral being moved past the critical strip, and then summed back over the characters. I don't specifically mean $d(n)$ - any $f$ will do.
I'm sure this kind of argument must be written down, if not in multiple places.
(I'm aware that things like Voronoi's formula is proven by pulling the integral past the critical strip. But what I'd really like to see is the sum back over characters - in my actual case this gets a bit involved and what I'm looking for is a sanity check with a well-known example.)

Probably you are already familiar with this, but you should look into the literature surrounding the divisor correlation problem / shifted divisor problem. The pre-DFI approaches to this problem involved opening one divisor function, which gives many sums of the type you describe, summed over many moduli $q$. In that setting (and possibly also in your setting?), it's slightly more convenient to use additive characters instead of multiplicative characters -- this gives rise to the Estermann function instead of Dirichlet L-functions.

(of course, morally they both are the same thing, but in this case it is psychologically easier to use additive characters since the functional equation of the Estermann function does not have a root number.)

One last comment: I don't really understand your first statement, namely that one could take their favourite multiplicative function instead of the divisor function if they like. I was under the impression that the tools towards proving exponent of distribution type results depend heavily on the exact nature of the multiplicative function in question.

I think your second comment is exactly why I want to see this application - I want to see how exactly one sums back over $\chi $, because as you say that is made more complicated by the root number. I'm aware of an argument using additive characters (Voronoi with a twist $e(na/q)$ is an example of this) but I have a general multiplicative $f$ so I think I really can't use additive characters. Your last comment: I guess I was just being vague.
